# Adding Numbers Generated By Random Number Generator in C

Tags: c, random, numbers, generator

before I ask my question I would like to point out that I did look for the answers already, and I didn't find what I was looking for.
Please bear in mind that I am a beginner in terms of programming, so please don't assume that I know everything there is to know.
Right, to the question.
My question is : How do I add together numbers that are created by random number generator ? The difficulty that I have is the fact that the number of randomly generated numbers could be different every time the program is ran. To make it clearer, the amount of randomly generated numbers is dependent on the input from user, eg if the input is 9, the program will generate 9 random numbers. This makes it difficult for me to come up with the idea of how to add the random numbers together and display them.
Here is the source code from my program. I think it is important to mention that the random numbers change every time I run the program, which is how I want them to be ( I used srand() with time, and rand() ). Also, the problem that I have currently is that the program doubles the last randomly generated number instead of adding them all together.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    int input;
    scanf("%d", &input);
    int i;
    int roll;
    int turn_total;
    time_t t;
    int sum;

    srand((unsigned) time(&t));             // the seed for the random number generator based on the current time

    for( i = 0; i < input; i++)
    {
        roll = (rand() % 6 + 1);            // random number generator 
        sum = roll+roll;                    // only dubbling the last roll for some reason = /
        printf("You Rolled : %d\n", roll);
    }

    printf("The Total Turn Score is : %d", sum);
}
```

Any help, ideas or clues would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Initialize `sum` to `0` and change `sum = roll+roll` to `sum = sum+roll;`.

Comment: Damn, I didn't expect anyone to answer that quick. It works perfectly now, thank you very very much. Could you explain the logic behind this to me, please ?

Comment: `sum += roll;` is shorter.

Comment: @Muffik9 You are adding `roll` twice and printing it. That means, it'll only print the very last input multiplied by 2 (i.e. `roll+roll`). Doing `sum = sum + roll` adds all the input numbers into `sum` and initializing it to `0` was necessary since automatic variables are not 0 initialized in C.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I understand your explanation. Hopefully I will not make the same mistake again. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo need to initialize sum first also you are not adding properly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
int input;
scanf("%d", &input);
int i;
int roll;
time_t t;
int sum = 0;

srand((unsigned) time(&t));                                 // the seed for    the random number generator based on the current time


for( i = 0; i < input; i++)
{
roll = (rand() % 6 + 1);                                    // random number generator 
  sum += roll;                                              // only dubbling the last roll for some reason = /
printf("You Rolled : %d\n", roll);
}

    printf("The Total Turn Score is : %d", sum);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) );
```

and initialize variable `sum`. For example

```
long long int sum = 0;

//...
sum += roll;
//...      
printf( "The Total Turn Score is : %lld", sum );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program is doubling the number that was generated because that's what you tell it to do in this line:

```
sum = roll+roll;
```

Instead, you need to add the current `roll` to the current value of `sum`:

```
sum = sum + roll;
```

And you need to initialize `sum` to 0 so that you start by adding just the first roll.

Think about it like rolling a dice multiple times and writing down what it was each time. You roll it once and get a 3, so you write down 3. You roll it again and get a 6, so you add 6 to the previous roll to get 9. You roll again and get 2, so you add 2 to 9 and get 11, and so on. The variable `sum` is where you write down the new number after every roll, but you're adding to what you wrote down before.

The way you had it before, you were completely disregarding the previous rolls. `rolls` in the loop only refers to the latest roll that you performed, and since the loop ends at some point, `sum` will be left as the sum of the last value of `roll`. This is why you were getting double the last number.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
sum = roll+roll
```

with

```
sum = roll+sum;
```